# The difference between "ぶら下がる" and "つり下がる" in terms of usage

Tags: word-choice, usage

As mentioned in the title, I want to ask about the difference between "ぶら下がる" and "つり下がる" in terms of usage. Both of them are translated as "hang".

For example

> 服が 鉄棒に つり下がる/ぶら下がる
>
> 手が つり革に つり下がる/ぶら下がる

Are the two words interchangeable?

Answer (score 3):

The only difference worth mentioning, as far as I am concerned, is in the word formation of the two words.

「ぶら下{さ}がる」 is formed by combining an ***onomatopoeia and a verb*** -- 「ぶら/ぶらり（と）」 and 「下がる」.

「つり下がる」 is formed by combining ***two verbs*** -- 「吊{つ}る」 and 「下がる」.

For using an onomatopoeia, 「ぶら下がる」 sounds just a tiny bit more informal and slightly more intuitive than 「つり下がる」 for the native speakers.  The difference is minimal in actual usage.  For this reason, I would say that the majority of native-speaking children would get to learn to say 「ぶら下がる」 before 「つり下がる」.

If you used the two interchangeably, I doubt if anyone would even notice anything.

Answer (score 2):

つり下がる and ぶら下がる are not always interchangeable.

- 服が 鉄棒に つり下がっている
- 服が 鉄棒に ぶら下がっている

are both correct but つり下がっている sounds like the clothing is attached firmly to the pull-up bar and ぶら下がっている sounds like the clothing is  hanging loose with the lower part fluttering in the breeze and not touching the ground.

- 手が つり革に つり下がる/ぶら下がる

is possible but very weird. Sounds to me that a forearm torn apart from its body is hanging.

Comment: How about omitting the "手"? 　電車に乗る時、つり革にぶら下がってください。

Comment: @chika 「つり革にぶら下がる」is grammatically fine, but... 電車に乗るときは、つり革につかまってください。つり革にぶら下がったら、たぶん怒られます。（

Comment: @chika, "電車に乗る時、つり革にぶら下がってください。" is grammatically correct, but is logically incorrect.
Because nobody wants you to work out hanging from the rings on the train as if a gymnast performed on the rings.
You probably hear a train announcement like "お立ちのお客様は、お近くのつり革、手すりにおつかまりください。"